# Como usar a cláusula WHERE em cima de uma coluna feita a partir do row_number() over()

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tentando usar o where em cima de uma coluna gerada pelo row_number mas não funciona; é possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, uma forma é através do uso de CTE.

```
-- código #1
with Sequenciado as (
SELECT *,
       seq= row_number() over (partition by colA order by colB)
  from tabA
)
SELECT seq, colA, colB
  from Sequenciado
  where seq between 1 and 5;
```

O código acima utiliza CTE (common table expression), que facilita a compreensão e manutenção do mesmo. Vide artigo “[Programação modular com expressões de tabela (CTE)](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/09/23/programacao-modular-com-expressoes-de-tabela-cte/)”.

Comment: Funcionou!! Obrigado amigo!

Answer (score 2):

Você também pode usar uma subconsulta:

```
SELECT seq, 
       colA, 
       colB
FROM
    (
        SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY colA ORDER BY colB) AS Seq
        FROM tabA
    ) AS T
WHERE T.Seq BETWEEN 1 AND 5;
```